# Common Rule for Multiple Input Fields pattern in Laravel

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-validation

I want to create a common rule for multiple Inpute fields with the name pattern "**name_***".
e.g.

I have multiple input fields with the following names:

- name
- name_fruit
- name_animal
- name_people
- name_region
- name_language
- description
- keywords
- image

And I want fields with pattern **name**, **name_*** should be `'required|min:3|max:120'` Validator.

Currently, I am using the following rule but it wonly works for the first input field **name**

```
    $rules = array(
        'name*'        => 'required|min:3|max:120',
     );
```

Is there any way using asterisk or regex or other method through which I can?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're better off just manually returning a rule array with every single one of those keys. It's easier to read.

```php
public function rules(): array
{
    return [
        'name'          => 'required|min:3|max:120',
        'name_fruit'    => 'required|min:3|max:120',
        'name_animal'   => 'required|min:3|max:120',
        'name_people'   => 'required|min:3|max:120',
        'name_region'   => 'required|min:3|max:120',
        'name_language' => 'required|min:3|max:120',
        'description'   => '...',
        'keywords'      => '...',
        'image'         => '...',
    ];
}
```

---

Of course, that doesn't mean you *can't* do what you want. But there is no built in wildcard like that. You'd have to write some extra logic.

```php
public function rules(): array
{
    $name_fields = ['name', 'name_fruit', 'name_animal', 'name_people', 'name_region', 'name_language'];

    $rules = [];
    foreach ($name_fields as $name_field) {
        $rules[$name_field] = 'required|min:3|max:120';
    }

    return $rules + [
        'description'   => '...',
        'keywords'      => '...',
        'image'         => '...',
    ];
}
```

---

Another option is to use array validation. For this to work, you'll need to change the `name` attribute of your inputs.

- From `name` to `name_fields[name]`
- From `name_fruit` to `name_fields[fruit]`
- From `name_animal` to `name_fields[animal]`
- From `name_people` to `name_fields[people]`
- From `name_region` to `name_fields[region]`
- From `name_language` to `name_fields[language]`

```php
public function rules(): array
{
    return [
        'name_fields'   => 'required|array',
        'name_fields.*' => 'required|min:3|max:120',
        'description'   => '...',
        'keywords'      => '...',
        'image'         => '...',
    ];
}
```

But this also means there's nothing validating against someone passing in an unkonwn field like say.... `name[company]` to give an example.

Comment: I preferred your second option but how to pass the error message?

Comment: Same way you'd do it normally

Comment: Passing each messages validator or variable??

Comment: If you need custom validation messages, use the messages() function inside the form request. If you're using a Validator instead, pass an array of validation messages as the third parameter validator(data, rules, messages).